# Put values in array and Get values using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

e.g. I have this Product Id values 31,32 from database. I want to put them on array. So, I can use the values for `foreach`.

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to get the stock of each product from database according to the given values (31,32).

**What I tried:**

```
$product_values = '31,32'; //this values can be different, sample values only
$arr_product_values = array();
$arr_product_values[] = $product_values;
foreach ($arr_product_values as $prod_id) {

  echo $prod_id;
 }
```

**Expected output:**

31 & 32

Comment: If id's are 31 and 32, do you want to multiply their stocks? Like stock of 31 * stock of 32? Simply multiplying 31*32 makes no sense

Comment: @ObjectManipulator typo man.

Comment: `print_r($arr_product_values );` and you'll find your array isn't what you expect

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr_product_values[] = $product_values;
```

That doesnt mean you have a new array with those 2 values now. You just took a comma separated string and assigned it to an array element, that doesnt make it an array itself.

```
$arr_product_values = array(31,32);
```

Does.

Now you can loop over it